# DocuSign Jwt Login issue c# api

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to login using JwtAuthorizationFlow with the DocuSign c# API and for some reason I get the following error with my own account:

```
Error calling Login: {\r\n  \"errorCode\": \"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED\",\r\n  \"message\": \"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.\"\
```

However when I try one of the test user info from that C# api, I'm able to log in using the exact same code.  This tells me that my DocuSign account is not properly configured?  How do I fix this issue?

**Update**:  I've stripped this down further to it's essence and using postman, I get a consent require error when trying to get a token:

```
{
    "error": "consent_required"
}
```

I'm not sure what to do here since I did follow the consent instructions.  BTW we're using org admin consent.

Comment: below is a sample code and where it fails (last line):

Comment: ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(config.Host);  apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow(Config.IntegratorKey,Config.UserId,Config.OAuthBasePath,pk,Config.ExpiresInHours);AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(apiClient.Configuration);LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question to add additional details. I've moved your comments into your question body.

Answer (score 0):

Which Confi‌​g.OAuthBasePath are you using? It should not include http:// or https://. Just the host name.

Comment: All the config is correct since I was able to use the test config from the C# API and that work.  Changing to use my jwt token fails.  I posted an updated to my answer-- it's a consent issue.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the instructions here on my browser and looks good now:  [link](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-using-the-oauth-jwt-flow/)

Comment: We are having the same issue. Can you elaborate on how you solved it? The link you sent isn't clear. We have 2 users. One works fine. The other does not. Both are provisioned on the same DocuSign plan.